# include entire caption in figure reference

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

I need to submit an article to a journal that has a really annoying format for the supplementary material (you guessed it, AGU!) and it entails places figures with captions using the \caption command but then repeating the captions verbatim in a separate part of the document. Cutting and pasting the captions when you make changes is tedious and therefore I was wondering if there was a way with the \ref command to include all the caption?  like this:

```
Fig. \ref{fig_lable} [all the caption copied here...]
```

?

Comment: What do you mean by "verbatim" in "repeating the captions verbatim"? Is this about the textual phrase in the output-file/.pdf-file? Is this about the .tex-input-file - i.e., do you need a collection of those snippets of code in the programming language TeX that formed arguments of the `\caption`-command? What documentclass is in use?  Probably the documentclass in use brings along a command `\listoffigures` which is similar to `\tableofcontents` but delivers a list of all figures instead of a list of section-titles. Probably packages hyperref, nameref or titleref are of interest.

Comment: just that I want to repeat the captions, at the moment I need to cut and paste them, which is a bit tedious.  I was just wondering if there was a way to pick them up automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find a small example below, exhibiting

- the cross-referencing-commands `\autoref` and `\nameref` of the [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)-package.
- the command `\listoffigures`. Due to the weird way in which registers for writing to external file are allocated in LaTeX you can have `\listoffigures` only once within your document. So I provided a command `\listoffiguresRepeatable` which can be repated as allocating the `\write`-register (and hereby destroying the .lof-file of the previous LaTeX-run) is delayed until the last page of the document is shipped out to  the output-file (.dvi-file/.pdf-file).

To make sure cross-referencing-data is captured at the right moment in time by `\label` as a rule of thumb always place the `\label`-command right behind the `\caption`-command.

The example needs to be compiled three times without having auxiliary files deleted between compilations.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

% In case you wish no hyperlinks and no bookmarks within the entire document:
\PassOptionsToPackage{bookmarks=false}{hyperref}%
\AtBeginDocument{\NoHyper}%
%  (I know that \NoHyper actually belongs to the NoHyper environment.
%   But NoHyper is an environment only because you normally want to
%   disable the creation of hyperlinks only locally. But since I don't
%   want to disable creation of hyperlinks locally, but for the whole 
%   document, I use the command directly.)
%
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{atveryend}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Repeatable@starttoc[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \@input{\jobname.#1}%
  \if@filesw
    \AfterLastShipout{%
      \@ifundefined{tf@#1}{%
        \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
        \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax 
      }{}%
    }%
  \fi
  \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup
}%

\newcommand\listoffiguresRepeatable{%
  \begingroup
  \let\@starttoc\Repeatable@starttoc
  \listoffigures
  \endgroup
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffiguresRepeatable

\noindent\hrulefill

\noindent
\autoref{first figure} is \nameref{first figure}. It is figure number~\ref{first figure} and you find it on page~\pageref{first figure}.

\noindent
\autoref{second figure} is \nameref{second figure}. It is figure number~\ref{second figure} and you find it on page~\pageref{second figure}.

\noindent\hrulefill

\noindent
Text accompanied by some figures.

\begin{figure}[ht]%
\centering
\caption{Caption of first figure}\label{first figure}%
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a.jpg}%
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]%
\centering
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-b.jpg}%
\caption{Caption of second figure}\label{second figure}%
\end{figure}

\noindent\hrulefill

\listoffiguresRepeatable

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case this is not of help to you, be more specific about your workflow and your needs.

A totally different approach to the matter could be maintaining databases containing info about your figures by means of the [datatool](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool)-package:

Database 1, at the begin of the current LaTeX-run obtaining data by reading a .csv-file that got created during the previous LaTeX-run, thus holding data from the previous LaTeX-run, used for accessing data during the current LaTeX run.

Database 2 used for storing data created during the current LaTeX-run and at the end of the current LaTeX-run written to .csv-file.

This way

- reading and storing data will not interfere.
- data created throughout an entire LaTeX-run is accessible throughout an entire LaTeX-run. I.e., data created at the end of a LaTeX-run is accessible at the begin of a LaTeX-run also.

(A mechanism is needed for comparing the two databases in order to find out whether data has changed between the previous and the current LaTeX-run and if so to raise a message about the need of re-running LaTeX.)

A variant of the `\caption`-command could be defined for—additionally to what the `\caption`-command already does—adding entries to Database 2.

A kind of `\listof...`-command could be defined for extracting data from Database 1 as needed.